# Using YQL to fetch place information

Tags: php, yql

Here is my query:

```
select * from geo.places where text="Swati Snacks";
```

I have a my latitude and longitude and name of the place with me, now I want to query "Yahoo" to fetch its maximum info stored in their database. By using the above variables I want to query it.

I have tried below query from Yahoo console but it sends wrong result the place is in Mumbai.

Comment: explain your question in detail which maximum value?

Comment: I am currently working on fetching maximum details like ratings,address,country,state etc..
Have worked it out with Google but Yahoo is Posing a problem..I have my Place name like Swati Snacks and its latitude longitude with me or in case i have the place zipcode i have fetch maximum details from yql to store in a csv

Answer (score 0):

You need to use as full address as possible like **Swati Snacks Mumbai India**.